# Сайт был виден по внешнему IP адресу?

Tags: ubuntu, веб-программирование, сервер, веб-сервер, vmware

Windows 10 хост, VMWare workstation, подключение интернета Bridge,
установил виртуальную машину Ubuntu server , 
на нее поставил 
Nginx, порты (22, 80, 5000) открыл, сайт залил. 
Внутри Ubuntu сайт виден по команде links 127.0.0.1:5000 .

Из хоста могу дотянуться до ubuntu по shh , по локальному адресу.
На роутере открыл порты  22, и 80.
Вводя в ping.eu/port-chk/ свой внешний IP пишет что 22 и 80 порты закрыты

Сайт не виден из вне по внешнему IP , подскажите как настроить ? 
Может что то  в настройках сети VMware ?

Comment: Это у вас в VMWare настроен Bridge? Тогда на роутере настроить перенаправление портов на этот самый локальный адрес виртуальной машины

Comment: Я так и сделал, роутер перезагрузил и всё равно не видит порт.

Comment: Причин «невидимости» порта может быть бесчисленное можество, от банальных опечаток до параноидального брандмауэра Windows. Без появления конкретной информации об устройстве сети помочь вряд ли получится

Comment: Для начала. Выложите `ss -ltn` и `iptables -S` с Ubuntu. А кто адреса у вас раздает? Роутер? В роутере выставьте статику на MAC Убунты (другой адрес, не тот, что сейчас), на Ubuntu получите адрес по DHCP. Результат, в студию!

Comment: Я вырубил вируталку и развернул IIS сервер на Windows 10 и там развернул сайт. Локально сайт открывается. Открыл в Файрволе порты, но всё равно из вне невидно их, такое впечатление что роутер мудрит. У меня Kenetic start. Сейчас буду смотреть в чём дело с портами...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том что у меня серый IP адрес, я так вычитал в данной статье 
https://help.keenetic.com/hc/ru/articles/213965789 
. Но это не точно я еще не проверил инфу на практике ! Данные из статьи:
Чтобы самостоятельно проверить, является ли ваш IP-адрес публичным "белым", можно воспользоваться сервисом myip.ru, myip.net (или любым подобным). Вам будет показан IP-адрес, под которым был произведен запрос на сайт; если он совпадает с IP-адресом, выданным интернет-провайдером на WAN-интерфейсе интернет-центра, значит, вам выдан публичный "белый" IP-адрес.

Comment: чтобы понять, что вас IP адрес серый, достаточно вспомнить, платите ли вы деньги за Белый IP адрес или нет. Если нет, то у вас серый.  
Белый IP адрес это дополнительная опция у провайдера. При чем выдается не всеми провайдерами, а только крупными. Эта опция стоит денег.

Comment: Раньше был другой провайдер, и без проплаты всё отлично работало, да IP менялся, но сервер был виден в инете.

Comment: некоторые провайдеры могут включать белый динамический ip себе в пакет по умолчанию. Пропишите статический IP своей виртуальной машине, чтобы она не по DHCP его получала. Перенаправьте порты на этот адрес. Проверьте брендмауеры винды и сервера. Вам надо проверить: 1) у вас серый, или белый. 2) если белый, то какой - статический или динамический. В случае если у вас серый - то до 80 порта вы никак не достучитесь. Если белый динамический - используйте Ddns